# example api vine javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

Я тут сутки не спал, поэтому помогите мне подумать.

Есть плеер Vine. У него есть апи https://dev.twitter.com/web/vine/oembed .
Можете сразу посмотреть все заголовки ответа тут https://vine.co/oembed.json?id=5xJVBXAunrD

Мне нужно с клиента получить данные
отправляю запрос

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://vine.co/oembed.json?id=5xJVBXAunrD',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: () => {
    console.log(arguments)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Получаю по лицу:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://vine.co/oembed.json?id=5xJVBXAunrD&callback=jQuery211011806981946079831_1482419611704&_=1482419611705'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

В общем, как я понял, **из-за того самого строго соответствия мне нужно все это "Добро" проксировать**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка происходит из-за того, что сервис отдает json, а dataType = jsonp.

Если бы сервис разрешал обращаться к себе с различных сайтов достаточно было бы просто заменить dataType на json. Но в данном случае сервис не разрешает и браузер выдаст ошибку

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

В качестве решение можно либо делать запрос к своему серверу, и уже с него делать серверными средствами запрос, либо воспользоваться одним из сервисов, например: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Пример:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://vine.co/oembed.json?id=5xJVBXAunrD',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: data => {
    console.log(data)
  },
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
к слову, сервис отдает нормально jsonp, ток заголовки не правильные... не знаю, так и задумывали? Или как всегда накосячили...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить контент тайп на `Content-Type: application/javascript`

Comment: да тоже самое будет